# What's the difference between wParam WM_NOTIFY and idFrom in NMHDR?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

[The documentation for `WM_NOTIFY` says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx):

> - `wParam`:
>     The identifier of the common control sending the message. This identifier is not guaranteed to be unique. An application should use the `hwndFrom` or `idFrom` member of the `NMHDR` structure (passed as the `lParam` parameter) to identify the control.

[And the documentation for `NMHDR` says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775514.aspx):

> - `idFrom`
>     An identifier of the control sending the message.

What exactly is the difference between these two?

Comment: I always thought they were the same thing.  If you're sending WM_NOTIFY, [sending the same thing for both works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1272422/292432).  The `idFrom` value, being a control ID, is definitely not a guaranteed unique identifier.  If you want to be sure, use hwndFrom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is in general no difference. It's a convenience. The same convenience that you get in the `WM_COMMAND` message, which passes both an ID and a window handle, even though you can derive the ID from the window handle via `GetDlgCtrlID`.